# archlinux: wifi connected but no internet where as internet works with wired

Tags: wireless-networking, arch-linux

I have wired and also wifi connection.

Wired connection internet works, while the internet of wifi not working

If connected to wired and also wifi the following is the output of ifconfig.

```
root@gauranga /home/simha # ifconfig 
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.5.113  netmask 255.255.248.0  broadcast 192.168.7.255
        inet6 fe80::66f9:5aa3:5449:bbf5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 68:f7:28:71:8d:be  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 736130  bytes 710984014 (678.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 181  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 278415  bytes 23924104 (22.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1428  bytes 369189 (360.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1428  bytes 369189 (360.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.5.245  netmask 255.255.248.0  broadcast 192.168.7.255
        inet6 fe80::14ac:2256:c091:2660  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 2e:dc:cd:0d:1f:82  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1237969  bytes 135361481 (129.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 4059  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 18074  bytes 2059915 (1.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

If using only wifi it pings to 192.168.0.1

```
$ ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=10.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=7.82 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=12.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=7.14 ms
```

whereas ping to google.com it does not show anything. it does not go further.

/etc/resolv.conf is

```
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

Also when on wifi:

```
simha@gauranga ~ % ip route show
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0  proto static  metric 600 
192.168.0.0/21 dev wlp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.5.245  metric 600
```

And when on wired:

```
simha@gauranga ~ % ip route show
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp2s0  proto static  metric 100 
192.168.0.0/21 dev enp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.5.113  metric 100
```

I am not able to understand the problem.

All this happened, after i upgraded archlinux.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you ping google.com, your PC tries to resolve the name to an IP address via a nameserver given in `/etc/resolv.conf` (without e at the end!).

Second, in case it was not a typo here on superuser.com, your nameserver points to 19**3**.168.0.1, not 19**2**.168.0.1. Therefore, it cannot resolve the name. Instead, your PC tries to get to 193.168.0.1 and does not find it. (Even if 19**3**.168.0.1 was your nameserver, it is not on the same network as 192.168.0.0/255.255.248.0. It does not have to be on the same network, but then the routing must be set up to know a route to the name server).

Then, check your routing table via `ip route show`, `ip route` or `ip r` (synonyms). In case there is no default route, add one via `ip route add default via 192.168.0.1`. After that, try `ping google.com` again.

Edit:
to configure the routes including the default route permanently, depending on your systemd version, use `netctl` or `systemd-networkd`. On my PCs, I tend to find `netctl` more stable in setting the routes than `systemd-networkd`.

Comment: I agree i had typo errors. resolve is resolv and 193.168.0.1 is 192.168.0.1. As i said the net works with wired and it uses the same resolv.conf. Also showed the `ip route show` output

Comment: Is the PC successfully connected to the Access Point? Is the access point handing out IP addresses via dhcp? Is 192.168.0.1 'firewalled' for specific IPs or wifi devices? (My wifi router will allow only certain MAC addresses access). Did you set up `iptables` on your system for `enp2s0` only maybe, and `wlp3s0` is not allowed to send to port 53/dns? Is the name server listening on its ethernet interface only, and not on the wireless interface? (In case your name server sits on the router as in my setup at home).

Comment: finally it on its own started working. In wifi setting: there is cloned Mac address. I deleted and kept it empty. then it worked

Comment: Adding router as default router with `ip route add default via 192.168.0.1` solved my problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Same case as mine where my device (Dell with [Broadcom](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/broadcom_wireless) [BCM43228](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/b43) where I manually installed the [b43-firmware](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/b43-firmware)) is connected to the (wireless) Wi-Fi (as it is visible in the router's connected devices) but it has no access to the internet (can't `ping`). I am using [iwd / `iwctl`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Iwd) as currently instructed in the [Arch Linux installation document](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/installation_guide#Connect_to_the_internet).

Some things to try:

- Notes:

  - You can directly try #5 below. It is the step that ultimately led to me being able to `ping google.com`
  - The commands below assume `wlan0` as the name of the device as visible in `ip link`. Adjust accordingly.

1. Start / restart the [iwd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Iwd) service

   ```
   sudo systemctl start iwd.service
   ```

   Install if it doesn't exist yet. Either use a wired ethernet connection to the router or connect an Android phone (that has access to the internet) and enable "Modem USB" for it to act as your wired connection. If it isn't possible within the Arch Linux environment, you can try using the Arch installer (bootable drive) then `mount` the hard disk drive `mount --mkdir /dev/sda2 /mnt/sda2` and `chroot` into that `arch-chroot /mnt/sda2`

   ```
   pacman -S iwd
   ```
2. [Enable the interface up](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration#Enabling_and_disabling_network_interfaces)

   ```
   ip link  # or ls /sys/class/net
   ip link set wlan0 up  # where wlan0 is the device name
   ```
3. Make sure you are [connected to the Wi-Fi](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Iwd#Show_device_and_connection_information).

   ```
   sudo iwctl device wlan0 show
   sudo iwctl station wlan0 show
   ```

   [Connect](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Iwd#Connect_to_a_network) if not yet connected

   ```
   sudo iwctl --passphrase mywifipassword station wlan0 connect MyWifiSsidName
   ```

   Also, access the router and view the connected devices to be sure you are connected.
4. To enable the automatic IP address assignment, [manually enable the built-in DHCP client](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Iwd#Enable_built-in_network_configuration) as described in the note within the [Wi-Fi connection steps](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Iwd#Connect_to_a_network).

   ```
   sudo cat >> /etc/iwd/main.conf 
   [General]
   EnableNetworkConfiguration=true
   ```
5. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328131/how-to-troubleshoot-dns-with-systemd-resolved) was the [step](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/432077/573504) that finally made it working for me.

   Check the system logs for any `error` or `fail` on things related to DNS. Mine showed `WARNING: src/resolve.c:resolve_systemd_set_dns() condition !systemd_state.is_ready failed`

   ```
   journalctl
   journalctl | grep -i dns
   ```

   Check if there is an error. Mine showed `Failed to set global data: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.`

   ```
   systemd-resolve --status
   ```

   Restart the service

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
   ```

   After this step, I was able to successfully `ping google.com`

For debugging, some useful commands are `dmesg` and `journalctl`.

Comment: Thanks, you brought the packets to my machine :)